# Are there any Luciad Developers?

Tags: framework, luciadmap

Doing a search of GIS.StackExchange, and all of StackOverflow, for the term "Luciad" will bring up zero relevant questions about the Luciad framework. From what I understand, it is comparable in many features to other libraries such as ESRI.

Why is it that no Luciad/LuciadMap questions are being asked or answered on any of these sites? Are there distinct disadvantages to the Luciad framework that prevent widespread adoption, or even discussion, of this framework?

Comment: Luciad is a GIS for Military Defence and Aviation so either too narrow a field or 'classified' as sensitive - What is the question you want to ask?

Comment: Of course, GRASS used to be a military GIS, so you never know, if Luciad was ever liberated into the FOSS realm, perhaps more people might use it - though even then as a system aimed at aviation (unlike GRASS), it would still be fairly niche I expect.

Comment: Would this be more appropriate over on meta?

Comment: Yes, perhaps this might have been better asked in meta. Apologies.

Comment: The first question is a meta question, but the second one is not.  I understand the second one to be the one of principal interest and the first is just motivational, so I think this was posted in the right place.

Comment: When Luciad software is told, it typically comes with a customer support contract. And in that case, customers typically just contact Luciad with whichever isues they have instead of posting their questions on a platform like this. This is pretty common for closed-source commercial products, especially products focusing on the corporate market.